# Russian Language Bold Font problem with newtxtext

Tags: babel, languages, bold, newtx, russian

I am writing an article in English, with some pages in Russian.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document} 
hello \textbf{hello} 
\selectlanguage{russian} привет \textbf{привет} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

hello **hello** привет привет

I am using `\selectlanguage{}` to switch between languages when needed.

However, I noticed that when I try to use `\textbf{}` when in Russian language mode, it does not work because of newtxtext, which I am using for math formulas.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: A simple example based on your code (`\documentclass[12pt]{article}     
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
hello \textbf{hello}
\selectlanguage{russian}
привет \textbf{привет}
\end{document}`; modulo line breaks) works for me. Please show us a small example document that shows what you are trying to do, a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: @moewe, you are totally right, your example works fine. I've looked into the packages I use, and it seems that newtxtext package is creating the problem I have. Do you know how to solve this problem without deleting this package? Thank you.

Comment: Please add that crucial piece of information to your question and consider turning the code fragment into a usable MWE (in the sense of the link above). Unfortunately, I don't know a lot about fonts, so you will have to wait for an expert to help you. But to my untrained eye it just seems as though the font does not have bold Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @moewe, I was hoping that my problem is too trivial to add it. Sorry, my bad. I have updated my question. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Strictly speaking the question might not require an MWE, but as you saw it is *much* easier if you include one because then you can be sure that we are all talking about the same thing and all seeing the same effect. The information about `newtxtext` was certainly crucial in understanding the issue.

Comment: @moewe totally agree. Moreover, only after your comment I was able to spot the problem with newtxtext...

Comment: Sure, my point is that if you had included an MWE from the start you would have realised that yourself without me asking.

Comment: @moewe understood, thank you. Still I wonder if there is a way to have bold for Russian text even with newtxtext.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get two warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 12.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/ntxtlf/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/ntxtlf/m/n' instead on input line 12.
```

because `newtxtext` doesn't support Cyrillic. Thus the standard font family is substituted (first warning), but the second substitution points back to the same font, because LaTeX knows nothing about `ntxtlf` in T2A encoding.

Solution: substitute with a font family using Times, but supporting Cyrillic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tempora} % this supports Cyrillic
\usepackage{newtxmath}


\begin{document}

English: hello \textbf{hello}

Russian: \foreignlanguage{russian}{привет \textbf{привет}}

\end{document}
```

Note that, in any case, `newtxmath` *must* be loaded after the font package for text, be it `tempora` or `newtxtext`.

[image]

You can use `newtxtext`, though, provided you set up Tempora for Cyrillic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}


\begin{document}

English: hello \textbf{hello}

Russian: \foreignlanguage{russian}{привет \textbf{привет}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this did the trick, thank you! However I am getting a new error because of using amsthm package: LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.
Is there a way to solve it? I need this package in the article.

Comment: @DarkTemplar Load `amsmath` and `amsthm` *before* `newtxmath`.

Comment: Perfect solution. I didn't know about `tempora`.